# Facing weird problem when trying to plot simple lat/ lon points

Tags: matplotlib, cartopy

I have following dataframe (corresponding csv is hosted here: http://www.sharecsv.com/s/3795d862c1973efa311d8a770e978215/t.csv)

```
            lat     lon
count   6159.000000     6159.000000
mean    37.764859   -122.355491
std     0.028214    0.038874
min     37.742200   -122.482783
25%     37.746317   -122.360133
50%     37.746417   -122.333717
75%     37.785825   -122.331300
max     37.818133   -122.331167
```

Following code plots correctly:

```py
    test_ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Mercator())
    test_ax.plot(test_df['lon'], test_df['lat'], color="blue", linewidth=4, alpha=1.0,
            transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
    plt.show()
```

[image: Plot1]

But if I take one subset, it doesn't:

```py
    test_ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Mercator())
    test_ax.plot(test_df['lon'][:1001], test_df['lat'][:1001], color="blue", linewidth=4, alpha=1.0,
            transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
    plt.show()
```

[image: Plot2]

But does so with another subset.

```py
    test_ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Mercator())
    test_ax.plot(test_df['lon'][:3501], test_df['lat'][:3501], color="blue", linewidth=4, alpha=1.0,
            transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
    plt.show()
```

[image: Plot3]

I am pretty sure I am doing something stupid, but I am just unable to figure the reason for this behaviour.

**Edit:**

On further experimentation I found that if I set the extent of map manually to include `0` meridian, the plot for the subset `:1001`, which wasn't showing earlier starts showing (the blue dot near San Francisco).

```py
    test_ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Mercator())
    test_ax.plot(test_df['lon'][:1001], test_df['lat'][:1001], color="blue", linewidth=4, alpha=1.0, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
    test_ax.coastlines()
    test_ax.set_extent([-130, 0, 30, 40], crs=ccrs.Geodetic())
    test_ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
    plt.show()
```

[image: Plot4]

**Edit: with reproducible example**

(For jupyter notebook)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import pandas as pd

df_csv_url = 'http://www.sharecsv.com/dl/76dd767525a37180ca54cd1d9314b9dc/t1.csv'
test_df = pd.read_csv(df_csv_url)
figure_params = { 'width': 9.6, 'height': 5.4 }

fig = plt.figure(
        figsize=(figure_params["width"], figure_params["height"])        
    )
test_ax = fig.add_axes((0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5), projection=ccrs.Mercator(), label="map1")
test_ax.plot(test_df['lon'], test_df['lat'], color="blue", linewidth=4, alpha=1.0, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
test_ax.coastlines()
test_ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
test_ax.set_title("Path doesn\'t show", y=1.5)

# Including 0 meridian in extent shows the path
test_ax1 = fig.add_axes((0, 0, 0.5, 0.5), projection=ccrs.Mercator(), label="map2")
test_ax1.plot(test_df['lon'], test_df['lat'], color="blue", linewidth=4, alpha=1.0, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
test_ax1.set_extent([-130, 0, 30, 40], crs=ccrs.Geodetic())
test_ax1.coastlines()
test_ax1.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
test_ax1.set_title("Path shows (blue dot near San Francisco)", y=1.1)

plt.show()
```

[image: Plot5]

**Edit**

(with simplified reproducible example)

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

test_df = pd.DataFrame()
test_df['lon'] = np.linspace(-120, -60, num=1000)
test_df['lat'] = 38

test_df1 = pd.DataFrame()
test_df1['lon'] = np.linspace(-120, -60, num=1001)
test_df1['lat'] = 38


fig = plt.figure()

meridian=0

test_ax = fig.add_axes((0, 0, 1, 0.6), projection=ccrs.Mercator())
test_ax.plot(test_df['lon'], test_df['lat'], color="blue", linewidth=4, alpha=1.0, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
test_ax.coastlines()
test_ax.set_extent((-125, meridian, 36, 38))
gl = test_ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
gl.xlabels_top = False
gl.ylabels_left = False
test_ax.set_title('Path with {} points, eastern edge={}'.format(len(test_df),meridian))


test_ax1 = fig.add_axes((0, 0.7, 1, 0.6), projection=ccrs.Mercator())
test_ax1.plot(test_df1['lon'], test_df1['lat'], color="red", linewidth=4, alpha=1.0, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
test_ax1.coastlines()
test_ax1.set_extent((-125, meridian, 36, 38))
gl1 = test_ax1.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
gl1.xlabels_top = False
gl1.ylabels_left = False
test_ax1.set_title('Path with {} points, eastern edge={}'.format(len(test_df1),meridian))


meridian=-10

test_ax2 = fig.add_axes((0, 1.4, 1, 0.6), projection=ccrs.Mercator())
test_ax2.plot(test_df['lon'], test_df['lat'], color="black", linewidth=4, alpha=1.0, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
test_ax2.coastlines()
test_ax2.set_extent((-125, -10, 36, 38))
gl2 = test_ax2.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
gl2.xlabels_top = False
gl2.ylabels_left = False
test_ax2.set_title('Path with {} points, eastern edge={}'.format(len(test_df),meridian))


test_ax3 = fig.add_axes((0, 2.1, 1, 0.6), projection=ccrs.Mercator())
test_ax3.plot(test_df1['lon'], test_df1['lat'], color="green", linewidth=4, alpha=1.0, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
test_ax3.coastlines()
test_ax3.set_extent((-125, -10, 36, 38))
gl3 = test_ax3.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
gl3.xlabels_top = False
gl3.ylabels_left = False
test_ax3.set_title('Path with {} points, eastern edge={}'.format(len(test_df1),meridian))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Would it work with `transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()`? (Honestly, I'm not sure if a geodetic transform makes sense or not with lat/lon coordinates)

Comment: I think it should...thought there can definitely be a gap in my knowledge as I am new to this. It is working correctly for two cases though as the shapes (and locations) are correct.

Comment: Not sure that comment answers my question.

Comment: OK. :-)

I answered this: I'm not sure if a geodetic transform makes sense or not with lat/lon coordinates

By: I think it should..

The answer to: Would it work with `transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()?`

Is: It doesn't. Just tried and same result.

Comment: This means that there might be a problem with the actual data. One could also start by making two plots into the same axes, one red one green and see if both appear as expected.

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. I tried what you suggested. The result is the same. Subset with `:1001` is not showing up, subset with `:3500` is. I have added an **Edit** to my question with the result of another experiment.

Comment: So your the first 1000 points are just not where you would expect them?

Comment: They don't display at all, unless `0` lon is included in extent, when they appear at the correct place.

Comment: Ok, one needs a [mcve] to replicate.

Comment: I have added a reproducible example to the question (jupyter notebook). Thanks again @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: This is pretty strange. If you pan the plot the data sometimes plotted and sometimes not. [animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEe6V.gif). I currently have no idea how to debug this.

Comment: I think the path shows up when '0' lon gets included in extent and hides when it does not.

Comment: I have added a simplified reproducible example @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. If you can take a look, it will be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I've just tried this out and if I've got more than 1000 points, and `test_ax1.set_extent([-130, 0, 30, 40], crs=ccrs.Geodetic())` is set, it works.  If I take that out, or if I set second value to anything less than 0, it doesn't show the data.  Could be this is a bug?

Comment: Thanks @MikeSperry for the trial & the edit. This does seem like a bug. I had added a Github issue: https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/1357

Comment: @virtualmic just to further confirm that this seems like a cartopy issue, and not a more general pyplot problem, the data plots completely normally when I reduce the code to `test_ax3 = fig.add_axes((0, 0.8, 1, 0.15))` and `test_ax3.plot(test_df1['lon'], test_df1['lat'], color="green", linewidth=4, alpha=1.0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been able to find another workaround. If the points are transformed prior to using the `plot` function (instead of passing the `transform` parameter), it works.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

test_df = pd.DataFrame()
test_df['lon'] = np.linspace(-120, -60, num=1000)
test_df['lat'] = 38

test_df1 = pd.DataFrame()
test_df1['lon'] = np.linspace(-120, -60, num=1001)
test_df1['lat'] = 38


fig = plt.figure()

meridian=0

test_ax = fig.add_axes((0, 0, 1, 0.6), projection=ccrs.Mercator())
test_ax.plot(test_df['lon'], test_df['lat'], color="blue", linewidth=4, alpha=1.0, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
test_ax.coastlines()
test_ax.set_extent((-125, meridian, 36, 38))
gl = test_ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
gl.xlabels_top = False
gl.ylabels_left = False
test_ax.set_title('Path with {} points, eastern edge={}'.format(len(test_df),meridian))


test_ax1 = fig.add_axes((0, 0.7, 1, 0.6), projection=ccrs.Mercator())
test_ax1.plot(test_df1['lon'], test_df1['lat'], color="red", linewidth=4, alpha=1.0, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
test_ax1.coastlines()
test_ax1.set_extent((-125, meridian, 36, 38))
gl1 = test_ax1.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
gl1.xlabels_top = False
gl1.ylabels_left = False
test_ax1.set_title('Path with {} points, eastern edge={}'.format(len(test_df1),meridian))


meridian=-10

test_ax2 = fig.add_axes((0, 1.4, 1, 0.6), projection=ccrs.Mercator())
test_ax2.plot(test_df['lon'], test_df['lat'], color="black", linewidth=4, alpha=1.0, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
test_ax2.coastlines()
test_ax2.set_extent((-125, -10, 36, 38))
gl2 = test_ax2.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
gl2.xlabels_top = False
gl2.ylabels_left = False
test_ax2.set_title('Path with {} points, eastern edge={}'.format(len(test_df),meridian))


test_ax3 = fig.add_axes((0, 2.1, 1, 0.6), projection=ccrs.Mercator())
test_ax3.plot(test_df1['lon'], test_df1['lat'], color="green", linewidth=4, alpha=1.0, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
test_ax3.coastlines()
test_ax3.set_extent((-125, -10, 36, 38))
gl3 = test_ax3.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
gl3.xlabels_top = False
gl3.ylabels_left = False
test_ax3.set_title('Path with {} points, eastern edge={}'.format(len(test_df1),meridian))


test_ax4 = fig.add_axes((0, 2.8, 1, 0.6), projection=ccrs.Mercator())
# Instead of transforming within the plot function, transform and then plot
transformed_points = ccrs.Mercator().transform_points(ccrs.Geodetic(), test_df1['lon'].values, test_df1['lat'].values)
test_ax4.plot([p[0] for p in transformed_points], [p[1] for p in transformed_points], color="green", linewidth=4, alpha=1.0)
test_ax4.coastlines()
test_ax4.set_extent((-125, -10, 36, 38))
gl3 = test_ax4.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
gl3.xlabels_top = False
gl3.ylabels_left = False
test_ax4.set_title('Path with {} prior transformed points, eastern edge={}'.format(len(test_df1),meridian))


plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Given there seems to be a some issue with cartopy at play, the best work around I see is to split your data into chunks of less than 1000, and then plot all parts of it.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

test_df = pd.DataFrame()
test_df['lon'] = np.linspace(-120, -60, num=1001)
test_df['lat'] = 38

fig = plt.figure()

meridian=0

test_ax = fig.add_axes((0, 0.05, 1, 0.3), projection=ccrs.Mercator())
test_ax.plot(test_df['lon'], test_df['lat'], color="red", 
                       linewidth=4, alpha=1.0, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
test_ax.coastlines()
test_ax.set_extent((-125, meridian, 36, 38))
gl = test_ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
gl.xlabels_top = False
gl.ylabels_left = False
test_ax.set_title('Path with {} points, eastern edge={}'.format(len(test_df),meridian))

meridian=-10

test_ax3 = fig.add_axes((0, 0.55, 1, 0.3), projection=ccrs.Mercator())
# plot first 500
test_ax3.plot(test_df['lon'][:500], test_df['lat'][:500], color="green", 
                        linewidth=4, alpha=1.0, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
# plot to cover the gap
test_ax3.plot(test_df['lon'][499:501], test_df['lat'][499:501], color="blue", 
                        linewidth=4, alpha=1.0, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
# plot last 501
test_ax3.plot(test_df['lon'][500:], test_df['lat'][500:], color="yellow", 
                        linewidth=4, alpha=1.0, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
test_ax3.coastlines()
test_ax3.set_extent((-125, -10, 36, 38))
gl3 = test_ax3.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
gl3.xlabels_top = False
gl3.ylabels_left = False
test_ax3.set_title('Path with {} points, eastern edge={}'.format(len(test_df),meridian))

plt.show()
```

For the case of 1001 points, I just split it into a section of 500 points and a section of 501 points.

[image: plot line in sections]

Since you are plotting the line, I also added the plot to cover the gap, shown in blue when you zoom in.

[image: zoom on gap]

The reason to set up the gap filler instead of overlapping the two sections comes in if you are also plotting the points, like this:

```
test_ax3.plot(test_df['lon'][:500], test_df['lat'][:500], color="green",
                        linewidth=1, alpha=1.0, transform=ccrs.Geodetic(), marker='.')
# plot to cover the gap
test_ax3.plot(test_df['lon'][499:501], test_df['lat'][499:501], color="blue",
                        linewidth=1, alpha=1.0, transform=ccrs.Geodetic(), marker=None)
# plot last 501
test_ax3.plot(test_df['lon'][500:], test_df['lat'][500:], color="yellow",
                        linewidth=1, alpha=1.0, transform=ccrs.Geodetic(), marker='.')
```

By separating out the filler, you can make sure you aren't duplicating points, which could be an issue if you have an alpha value of less than `1.0`.

[image]

Applying this to your original data, you can create a function to loop over the dataframe in chunks equal to whatever size you want.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import pandas as pd

PLOT_LIMIT = 1000

df_csv_url = 'http://www.sharecsv.com/dl/76dd767525a37180ca54cd1d9314b9dc/t1.csv'
test_df = pd.read_csv(df_csv_url)
figure_params = { 'width': 9.6, 'height': 5.4 }

fig = plt.figure(
        figsize=(figure_params["width"], figure_params["height"])
    )

print(len(test_df['lon']))

def ax_plot(test_ax, test_df):
    # this function will loop over the dataframe in chunks equal to PLOT_LIMIT
    len_df = len(test_df)
    n=0
    for i in range(len_df//PLOT_LIMIT):
        test_ax.plot(test_df['lon'][1000*i:1000*(i+1)], test_df['lat'][1000*i:1000*(i+1)], color="blue",
                        linewidth=4, alpha=1.0, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
        if (len_df-((n+1)*PLOT_LIMIT)) != 0:
            test_ax.plot(test_df['lon'][(1000*i)-1:(1000*(i+1))+1], test_df['lat'][(1000*i)-1:(1000*(i+1))+1], color="blue",
                            linewidth=4, alpha=1.0, transform=ccrs.Geodetic(), marker='None')
        n+=1

    test_ax.plot(test_df['lon'][1000*n:], test_df['lat'][1000*n:], color="blue",
                    linewidth=4, alpha=1.0, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())


test_ax1 = fig.add_axes((0, 0.55, 1, 0.45), projection=ccrs.Mercator(), label="map1")
ax_plot(test_ax1, test_df)
test_ax1.coastlines()
test_ax1.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
test_ax1.set_title("Path shows", y=1.5)

# Including 0 meridian in extent shows the path
test_ax2 = fig.add_axes((0, 0.1, 1, 0.45), projection=ccrs.Mercator(), label="map2")
ax_plot(test_ax2, test_df)
test_ax2.set_extent([-130, -30, 30, 40], crs=ccrs.Geodetic())
test_ax2.coastlines()
test_ax2.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
test_ax2.set_title("Path shows (blue dot near San Francisco)", y=1.1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

As you can see, you should now have flexibility in setting the viewing window on the map.  I haven't checked edge cases like crossing the antimeridian, but in the cases presented it is working.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer and the workaround. I will try it out and let you know how it goes as my actual application is bit more complex than these scenarios.

Comment: I have been able to figure out another workaround (which I still need to try in the actual scenario, but works in the current). I have added that as another answer.

Comment: I tried the other workaround for my actual use-case (where I had to plot more than 7000 plots) and it worked good. Using it for now...thanks for all the help @Mike Sperry!